# Convert Coldfusion script in Oracle view with CASE and iteration

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, case

I created a coldfusion script allowing to get an object "unit" from an array.

My DB has a view about units. For a same unit key "ORG_ID", it can exist several rows (with a difference on a field "origin"). the field "origin" can be "current", "history" or "different".

```
+---------+---------+------------+------------+----------|
|  ORG_ID |  TITLE  | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO   |  ORIGIN  |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+----------|
| 1234    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/9999 | other    |
| 1234    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/3333 | current  |  
| 1234    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/9999 | history  |  
| 5420    | A.2     | 01/01/2014 | 31/12/3333 | other    |
| 9876    | A.3     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/3333 | current  |  
| 9876    | B.3     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/9999 | history  |  
| 5527    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/2199 | current  |
| 5527    | D.2     | 01/01/2010 | 31/12/2015 | history  |  
| 5527    | A.1     | 01/01/2016 | 31/12/2199 | history  |  
| 6699    | E.5     | 01/01/2016 | 31/12/2017 | history  |
| 6699    | A.4     | 01/01/2017 | 31/12/2018 | history  |    
+---------+---------+------------+------------+----------|
```

In this case for instance here the result that I would like to get:

```
+---------+---------+------------+------------+----------|--------------|
|  ORG_ID |  TITLE  | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO   |  ORIGIN  | CORRECT_VERS |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+----------|--------------|
| 1234    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/9999 | other    |      0       |    
| 1234    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/3333 | current  |      1       |  
| 1234    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/9999 | history  |      0       |  
| 5420    | A.2     | 01/01/2014 | 31/12/3333 | other    |      1       |
| 9876    | A.3     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/3333 | current  |      1       |  
| 9876    | B.3     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/9999 | history  |      0       |  
| 5527    | A.1     | 01/03/2016 | 31/12/2199 | current  |      1       |
| 5527    | D.2     | 01/01/2010 | 31/12/2015 | history  |      0       |  
| 5527    | A.1     | 01/01/2016 | 31/12/2199 | history  |      0       |  
| 6699    | E.5     | 01/01/2016 | 31/12/2017 | history  |      0       |
| 6699    | A.4     | 01/01/2017 | 31/12/2018 | history  |      0       |    
+---------+---------+------------+------------+----------+--------------|
```

***My Coldfusion script:*** dataUnitArray contains the list of units in an array

```
<cftry>         

    <cfset hist = 0/>
    <cfset unit = structNew() />    

    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(dataUnitArray)#">  

        <cfif #dataUnitArray[i].ORIGIN# EQ "current">
            <!---  Unit is current  --->
            <cfscript>
                unit.ORG_ID = #dataUnitArray[i].ORG_ID#;        
                unit.TITLE = #dataUnitArray[i].TITLE#;      
                unit.UNIT_VALID_FROM = #dateFormat(dataUnitArray[i].UNIT_VALID_FROM, 'DD/MM/YYYY')#;    
                unit.UNIT_VALID_TO = #dateFormat(dataUnitArray[i].UNIT_VALID_TO, 'DD/MM/YYYY')#;        
                unit.ORIGIN = #dataUnitArray[i].ORIGIN#;        

                return unit;
            </cfscript>     

        <cfelse>
            <cfif #dataUnitArray[i].ORIGIN# EQ "history">
                <!---  Unit is history  --->
                <cfscript>
                    unit.ORG_ID = #dataUnitArray[i].ORG_ID#;        
                    unit.TITLE = #dataUnitArray[i].TITLE#;      
                    unit.UNIT_VALID_FROM = #dateFormat(dataUnitArray[i].UNIT_VALID_FROM, 'DD/MM/YYYY')#;    
                    unit.UNIT_VALID_TO = #dateFormat(dataUnitArray[i].UNIT_VALID_TO, 'DD/MM/YYYY')#;        
                    unit.ORIGIN = #dataUnitArray[i].ORIGIN#;        
                </cfscript>

                <cfset hist++ >

            <cfelse>
            <!---  Unit is different (other) --->
                <cfif hist EQ 0>

                    <cfscript>
                        unit.ORG_ID = #dataUnitArray[i].ORG_ID#;        
                        unit.TITLE = #dataUnitArray[i].TITLE#;      
                        unit.UNIT_VALID_FROM = #dateFormat(dataUnitArray[i].UNIT_VALID_FROM, 'DD/MM/YYYY')#;    
                        unit.UNIT_VALID_TO = #dateFormat(dataUnitArray[i].UNIT_VALID_TO, 'DD/MM/YYYY')#;        
                        unit.ORIGIN = #dataUnitArray[i].ORIGIN#;        
                    </cfscript>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>

        </cfif>     

    </cfloop>

    <cfscript>
        return unit;
    </cfscript>

    <cfcatch type="any">                
        <cfscript>
            .....
        </cfscript>         
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

My script is correctly working. But I have loading time problem when I used it on a lot of data. That's why I would like to do that directly in ORACLE, with CASE...WHEN as:

```
CASE
    when ORIGIN = 'current' THEN 1 
    WHEN ORIGIN = 'history' THEN
        CASE  hist = 0 THEN ....

        END
ELSE 
   0   
END  AS "IS_CORRECT_VERSION"
```

I would like to add a new column "CORRECT_VERSION" ( value 0 or 1 when the version is correct) in a view in order to retrieve the correct unit version.

But I don't know how to do that, could you please help me with that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Seb

Comment: I am not expert of cold fusion but oracle. So can you please edit the question and share the sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hi, I added the output desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know ColdFusion, but I think I understood the logic. Priority is current > history > different. It is not clear which row is correct when there are two `current` rows or only `different` rows, so I mark row with minimum `valid_from` in such case. If you don't care You can omit this parameter (remove `unit_valid_from` from `row_number`'s `order by` clause):

```
select units.*, 
       case when 1 = 
           row_number() over (
               partition by org_id 
               order by case origin when 'current' then 1 when 'history' then 2 else 3 end, 
                        unit_valid_from ) then 1 else 0 end as is_correct_version
  from units
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=799bc4b9e1958e474da1b812b86e3db2)</sup>**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I create now a view with your code. I have another problem linked to that. I have meetings linked to the unit. Several meeting can have the same version of unit. When I do the link between the meeting and the unit (based on the ORG_ID), I saw that just the last meeting of the list (with the field origin='current') has the field correct_version to 1. All the others meetings have the field to 0. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood. If you want only rows with correct_version then make join on `meeting.org_id = view_units.org_id and correct_version = 1`. You can also filter only rows which are "first", like in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41dc026a606fb9f818e5e465ac0f1742), and do not use this column at all when joining.

Comment: I do the view meeting_unit_v linked with the meeting_id by updating that and it seems working:`select meeting_id, units.*, 
       case when 1 = 
           row_number() over (
               partition by org_id, meeting_id 
               order by case origin when 'current' then 1 when 'history' then 2 else 3 end, 
                        unit_valid_from ) then 1 else 0 end as is_correct_version
  from meeting_unit_v`. But Im' a little lost. So for my knowledge could you please me the code ` row_number() over (
               partition by....`

Comment: Looks correct. My only doubt is which row you want if there are two _current_ values. If you want newest then last part of `order by` should be `unit_valid_from DESC` (descending order). If you want first use ascending, default order. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) and example of row_number().

Comment: There is only one "current" or only one "other" in our system but it's possible to have several "history" by unit (and so by meeting). In this last case only the first one corresponding with the date should chosen.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that there are no two rows having the same origin for the same org_id and even if duplicates exist, there must be only one record has VALID_FROM < SYSDATE < VALID_TO.

Following is the solution based on sample data. Please change the logic if required.

```
SELECT
    UNITS.*,
    CASE
        WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER(
            PARTITION BY ORG_ID
            ORDER BY
                CASE ORIGIN
                    WHEN 'current'   THEN 1
                    WHEN 'history'   THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END
        ) = 1
             AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN VALID_FROM AND VALID_TO THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS IS_CORRECT_VERSION
FROM
    UNITS;
```

Cheers!!